# If URL contains 6 digit number append the value to a class

Tags: jquery, regex, append, href

My apologies if this has been answered. I have tried searching however being fresh at this maybe I'm not using the right terminology.

I have a page with links to pdfs example below:

```
<a href="https://www.pdflinks.com/files/190488/nameoffile.pdf">Link1</a>
<a href="https://www.pdflinks.com/files/112254/nameoffile.pdf">Link2</a>
```

If a URL contains 6 digits (as above) and .pdf can these values be added to the href as a class using regex and JQuery? So the result being:

```
<a href="https://www.pdflinks.com/files/190488/nameoffile.pdf" class="pdf190488">Link1</a>
<a href="https://www.pdflinks.com/files/112254/nameoffile.pdf" class="pdf112254">Link2</a>
```

I have tried the following but no cigar

```
var regex = "^[0-9]{1,6}$";
$('a').each(function() {
    $(this).addClass(regex.match($(this).attr("href"))[0]
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There were several errors:

- The regex was anchored: there was no match
- The regex as wrongly initialized
- Use the method `exec` instead of `match`
- The JS was invalid (missing closing parenthesis)

```js
var regex = /[0-9]{1,6}/;
$('a').each(function() {
  $(this).addClass('pdf' + regex.exec($(this).attr("href"))[0]);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="https://www.pdflinks.com/files/190488/nameoffile.pdf">Link1</a>
<a href="https://www.pdflinks.com/files/112254/nameoffile.pdf">Link2</a>
```

Also, if you meant *exactly 6 digits*, change regex to `[0-9]{6}`

Comment: Thank you Ayoub. This did the trick. Appreciate the explanation.

Comment: 1 quick question. The code you supplied works as expected however if there is a URL that does not qualify (doesn't contain 6 digits) it fails to work on any other link past that point. example: 

    <a href="https://www.files/190488/nameoffile.pdf">L1</a>
    <a href="https://www.files/nameoffile.pdf">L2</a>
    <a href="https://www.files/112254/nameoffile.pdf">L2</a>

The result is:
    <a href="https://www.files/190488/nameoffile.pdf" class="%test:190488%">L1</a>
    <a href="https://files/nameoffile.pdf">L2</a>
    <a href="https://files/112254/nameoffile.pdf">L3</a>

Comment: Any thoughts Thomas?

Answer (score 2):

There's a few problems with your code:

1. Your regular expression, `"^[0-9]{1,6}$"`

This is saying you are expecting a number, 1 to 6 characters long, that is at the beginning of the string and is also the end. You are also setting is as a string, whereas you could use an actual expression:

```
var regex = /[0-9]{1,6}/g;
```

2. `regex.match` is not a method.

You are calling `match` as a method on the regular expression, but it is actually the other way around. `match` is a method on Strings.

```
$(this).attr('href').match(regex)[0]
```

An update to your code could be as follows:

```js
var regex = /[0-9]{1,6}/g;

$('a').each(function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  $this.addClass('pdf' + $this.attr('href').match(regex)[0]);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="https://www.pdflinks.com/files/190488/nameoffile.pdf">Link1</a>
<a href="https://www.pdflinks.com/files/112254/nameoffile.pdf">Link2</a>
```

There are a few ways you could improve this, including checking for the existence of the match before adding the class.

Comment: Thanks chazsolo for the explanation and alternative solution.

Answer (score 0):

For the above url:

```
$('a').each(function() {
  var path = $(this).attr("href");
  var str = path.split("/");
  var fileName = str[5].split(".");
  var className = fileName[1]+str[4];
  $(this).addClass(className);
});
```